# np.where treatment of np.nan (NaNs evaluated as value < 0)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I am using np.where to conduct a logic test of floats to determine whether the value is > or < 0. There are np.nan values in the pandas dataframe due to the calculation, and I would like the np.where function to "ignore" the np.nan rows - in other words, keep that row as a np.nan. How can I do this?

Here is an example with some dummy data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create some dummy data with datetime index
prices = [100, 99, 98, 101, 102, 99]
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/06/2018')
so_df = pd.DataFrame(prices, index=dates)
so_df.columns = ['Close']

#calculate daily % changes
so_df['pct_change'] = so_df.Close.pct_change()

#logic test to determine if pct_change > 0 or not
so_df['greater_zero?'] = np.where(so_df['pct_change'] > 0, 1, 0)
```

Looking at the dataframe, we can see that the first row is a np.nan and yet numpy is evaluating this as a value less than zero, which is incorrect. This should just be a np.nan.

```
    Close   pct_change  greater_zero?
2018-01-01  100 NaN 0
2018-01-02  99  -0.010000   0
2018-01-03  98  -0.010101   0
2018-01-04  101 0.030612    1
2018-01-05  102 0.009901    1
2018-01-06  99  -0.029412   0
```

Looking at the [np.where documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) there doesn't seem to have an embedded argument on how to treat np.nan values. I have also tried to embed multiple np.where functions but wasn't able to get that to work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this:

```
so_df['greater_zero?'] = np.where(np.isnan(so_df['pct_change']), so_df['pct_change'], (so_df['pct_change'] > 0).astype(int))

print(so_df)
```

**Output**

```
            Close  pct_change  greater_zero?
2018-01-01    100         NaN            NaN
2018-01-02     99   -0.010000            0.0
2018-01-03     98   -0.010101            0.0
2018-01-04    101    0.030612            1.0
2018-01-05    102    0.009901            1.0
2018-01-06     99   -0.029412            0.0
```

Basically where is NaN use the same value otherwise use the value of the comparison directly

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to set `NaN` values:

```
so_df['greater_zero?'] = np.where(so_df['pct_change'] > 0, 1, 0)
so_df['greater_zero?'].mask(so_df['pct_change'].isna(),np.nan,inplace=True)

print(so_df)

            Close  pct_change  greater_zero?
2018-01-01    100         NaN            NaN
2018-01-02     99   -0.010000            0.0
2018-01-03     98   -0.010101            0.0
2018-01-04    101    0.030612            1.0
2018-01-05    102    0.009901            1.0
2018-01-06     99   -0.029412            0.0
```

or [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
so_df['greater_zero?'].where(so_df['pct_change'].notna(),np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not useful to you any more, but you can take the advantage of the fact that multiplying `NaN` with anything returns `NaN`. So a one-line solution would be:

```
so_df['greater_zero?'] = np.where(so_df['pct_change'] > 0, 1, 0*so_df['pct_change'])

print(so_df)

            Close  pct_change  greater_zero?
2018-01-01    100         NaN           NaN
2018-01-02     99   -0.010000          -0.0
2018-01-03     98   -0.010101          -0.0
2018-01-04    101    0.030612           1.0
2018-01-05    102    0.009901           1.0
2018-01-06     99   -0.029412          -0.0
```